# Matlab plot legend include a fraction and a mathematical symbol

Tags: matlab

I wanted to print a fraction (\frac{W}{m^2}) and mathematical symbol (Deg c) in the legend of the plot in MATLAB.

```
Tc = [10,20,30]
legend('300 \frac{W}{m^2}, %.f °C',Tc(1));
```

It is not working. Giving following error

```
Error using legend (line 261)
Invalid argument. Type 'help legend' for more information.

Error in DifferentSixePVarrays_configurations_IVcurves (line 95)
legend('300, %.f °C',Tc(1),'400','500','600','700','800','900','1000'); % $$\frac{W}{m^2}$$,%.f °C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the maths symbols, you are inputting an integer (`Tc(1)`) and that is invalid.

It seems that what you want is to create a string using `Tc(1)`. You need to do that in a separate step, not as an input to `legend`. You can do that with either standard string concatenation, i.e. `['300 ', num2str(Tc(1)), ' °C']` or with `sprintf` which allows that "C style" string definition (the `%f` stuff).

On that note, you may need to set the interpreter to Latex, and you may need to add the Latex equivalent to `°` for it to work, but this is secondary, not the cause of your error.

Comment: It this a right way to print many legends: `Legend = cell(length(Phi),1);
 for iter=1:length(Phi)
   Legend{iter}=string(num2str(Phi(i)),num2str(Tc(i)));
 end
legend(Legend)`

Comment: Have you tested it? This code is suddenly all different, how is it related to your question? You can read the docs, it has nice examples on different ways of using `legend`

Comment: You can do it with the default Tex Interpreter and use  `\circ` for the `°` symbol.

Comment: @Mainland If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Please use the comments to request clarification or leaving constructive criticism about the answer. Please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @SardarUsama I have posted a new question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938400/matlab-plot-for-loop-legend-with-fraction

Comment: I have posted a new question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938400/matlab-plot-for-loop-legend-with-fraction

Comment: @Mainland Please close this question if your query has been answered or give feedback to the answer poster how and why it doesn't answer the question