# Plot for loop legend with fraction

Tags: matlab, for-loop, latex, legend, matlab-figure

I am using MATLAB R2018b. I have a `for` loop plot. I am struggling with `legend` which has fraction in it.

My code and present output:

```
% Plot 
ColorVec = hsv(length(Phi));
markers = {'+','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'};
figure;
set(gca,'fontsize',24,'fontname','Times New Roman');
hold on;
for k = 1:length(Nse)
    for i=1:length(Iph)
             plot(V11(:),P(:),'-','color',ColorVec(i,:),'Linewidth',2.0);
    end
end
%%% Following for legend
Legend = cell(length(Phi),1);
 for iter=1:length(Phi)
   Legend{iter}=strcat(num2str(Phi(iter)),'\frac{W}{m^2},',num2str(round(Tc(iter))),' °C ');
 end
hl = legend(Legend);
set(hl ,'Interpreter','latex')
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you need the $

Comment: @AnderBiguri I removed $ and reran the code. No change. The problem still persists.  I updated my code to give a clear picture of what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`°` is not recognizable by Latex and the fraction should be enclosed inside `$_____$`. You should be using `$^\circ$` for getting `°` with the Latex Interpreter.

i.e. instead of what you have in your loop, you should be having:

```
Legend{iter}=strcat(num2str(Phi(iter)),'$\frac{W}{m^2}$,',...
    num2str(round(Tc(iter))),'$^\circ$C');
```

or even simpler with the power of strings (instead of characters):

```
Legend{iter} = Phi(iter) + "$\frac{W}{m^2}$," + round(Tc(iter)) + "$^\circ$C";
```

**Result*:**

[image]

* <sup>Ignore the colors</sup>